# How To Use Wrap Function In Vs Code For Flutter Coding?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

How To Use Wrap Function In Vs Code For Flutter Coding ?
I want to  know shortcut key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the code, than alt+Enter. You'll see below picture, now choose Extract method. Did you mean this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap with `Column`/`Row` widget, then rename it to `Wrap`. Both provide `children`.

1st `ctrl+shift+r` on windows(default I think)

[image]

You will get

[image]

Now rename it to `Wrap`